# How to keep the state of my bottomNavigationBar Cubit BLoc Flutter?

Tags: flutter, bloc, cubit

I have the problem that when I start the application my map appears one way and then on passing from the bottomnavigatioBar tab it gets completely redrawn when I return.

I think it is a problem with the block and state map.

I need to know what the solution would be so that it does not get redrawn, that is, if I leave the map in a position and step in the tab, when I come back, it looks where I left it.

my map bloc:

```
     class MapaBloc extends Bloc<MapaEvent, MapaState> {
  MapaBloc() : super(new MapaState());

  GoogleMapController _mapController;

  void initMapa(GoogleMapController controller) {
    {
      this._mapController = controller;
      this._mapController.setMapStyle(jsonEncode(testMapTheme));

      add(OnMapaListo());
    }
  }

  void moverCamara(LatLng destino) {
    final cameraUpdate = CameraUpdate.newLatLng(destino);
    this._mapController?.animateCamera(cameraUpdate);
  }

  @override
  Stream<MapaState> mapEventToState(MapaEvent event) async* {
    if (event is OnMapaListo) {
      yield state.copyWith(mapaListo: true);
    }
  }
}
```

my map event:

```
@immutable
abstract class MapaEvent {}

class OnMapaListo extends MapaEvent {}
```

my map state

```
@immutable
class MapaState {
  final bool mapaListo;

  MapaState({this.mapaListo = false});

  MapaState copyWith({bool mapaListo}) =>
      MapaState(mapaListo: mapaListo ?? this.mapaListo);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless there's something else triggering a rebuild on those pages you didn't show, should be as simple as adding the `AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin` that you're using on your home page, to all the other screens.

Comment: I have tried but it keeps redrawing completely. I think it must be a problem with the bloc and state.

I added that code in case you can think of what the problem would be.

Comment: I'll have a look at this tomorrow but you should also show the code you have for the pages that are rebuilding when you don't want them to.